# Jasperreports: HTML component with external JavaScript File - HTML Export fails on Server (but not in Ireport)

Tags: javascript, jasper-reports, jasperserver, html-components

I wanted to chart data with the Google Chart API and display the result in Jasperserver Pro 5.2. I created a HTML-Componente containing the the full HTML code inclusive the 
`<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'>` tag.
The HTML Export works fine in iReport, but the HTML Component remains empty when called  on jasperserver. There is no error message.
(btw: when called from iOS 7.0.1 (jaspersoft app) with my iphone the page is displayed correctly.)  I tried with different browsers, but always the same thing.

Can anyone help?

Please find attached the JRXML

This is the JRXML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="HtmlComponentReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="515" leftMargin="40" rightMargin="40" topMargin="50" bottomMargin="50" uuid="b4ad5fd2-ee36-4fc4-a326-5600945b4633">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="JRProjectID" class="java.lang.Integer">
<defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Integer.valueOf(287)]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter>
<parameter name="chart" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
 <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script><script type='text/javascript'>google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});; google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);function drawChart() {var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');data.addRows('Mushrooms', 3],['Onions', 1],['Olives', 1],['Zucchini', 1],['Pepperoni', 2);var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night', 'width':400,'height':300};var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));chart.draw(data, options);}</script></head><body><div id='chart_div' style='width:400; height:300'></div></body></html>"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
 <queryString>
 <![CDATA[select 1 as dummy]]>
 </queryString>
<field name="dummy" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
 <title>
 <band height="502">
 <componentElement>
 <reportElement uuid="13361114-deb3-40d4-be5d-913b157ba7d3" x="0" y="0" width="515" height="472" backcolor="#ADD8E6"/>
  <hc:html xmlns:hc="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/htmlcomponent.xsd" scaleType="FillFrame" horizontalAlign="Left" verticalAlign="Top">
     <hc:htmlContentExpression><![CDATA[$P{chart}]]></hc:htmlContentExpression>
 </hc:html>
 </title>
    </jasperReport>
```

Thanks for your help!